# jQuery Bind Toggle in Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to bind click events via loop.

This works fine as long as I reference relative to the original bind (using `this`). Problem is, it is unrealistic use `this` since the elements I'm toggling are in a separate part of the DOM.

Results, line 4 will always reference "image" in this situation.

Coffeescript:

```
for name in ["contact", "kws", "image"]
  $("#expand-#{name}").bind('click', ->
    $(this).toggleClass("icon-plus-sign").toggleClass("icon-minus-sign")
    $(".#{name}-expander").toggle()
  )
```

Sadly, all I figure is to repeat code.

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a variable scope problem. `name` will always be the last value assigned by the time your handlers run.

Coffeescript provides the [do](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) keyword to generate a self-calling closure and give the appropriate scope to `name`:

```
for name in ["contact", "kws", "image"]
    do (name) ->
        $("#expand-#{name}").bind('click', ->
            $(this).toggleClass("icon-plus-sign").toggleClass("icon-minus-sign")
            $(".#{name}-expander").toggle()
        )
```